# how to get the previous selected data from tableview on submit button action

Tags: ios

this is my code in the button action.

```
 @IBAction func forward(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 let totalSections = questionViewModel.numberOfSections()


        for section in 0..<totalSections {


            let totalRows = questionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section:section)


              questionViewModel.search(indexPath: IndexPath(row: totalRows, section: section))
             print(questionViewModel.OptionListArray)



            if ((questionViewModel.OptionListArray?.count)! >= 1) {
                                print(questionViewModel.OptionListArray?.count)


                                continue
                            } else {

                                // Show alert
                                print("Please select item at",(section))

                                let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: section)
                                print(questionModel.question)

                                let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Please Select any option from question", message:(questionModel.question), preferredStyle: .alert)
                                // Create the actions
                                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                                    UIAlertAction in
                                    NSLog("OK Pressed")
                                    self.viewDidLoad()


                                }
                                controller.addAction(okAction)
                                //  controller.addAction(cancel)

                                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                self.viewDidLoad()


                                break
                            }


        }


}
```

So according to this code.I have button action.I have tableview in viewcontroller .tableview is grouped .so after selecting the rows i need to validate whether i have selected one row from each section.For that i have used this code.So when i select only the data of section1 then click on submit button.then it will show alert to select the section2.But when i click on section2 data then click on submit button then it will show to select section1 data.But i have previous selected the section1 data.So to fix the problem.

Comment: What does `search` do in your view model? Note, you can use `.isEmpty` rather than count > 0 and you shouldn't call view lifecycle functions, such as `viewDidLoad` directly

Comment: then at the alert what should do?

Comment: @Paulw11   what modification should i do?

Comment: I can't tell you, because you haven't shown how you are checking whether a section contains a selection. As I told you last week you would make your life much simpler if you abandoned the viewmodel and just got your code working with a simple view controller.  You can then move functions into a view model if you like

Comment: @Paulw11 i just want to know that .u told there is no need to call the lifecycle functions such ass viewDidLoad at that place what should call?

Comment: I don't know. Why are you calling it?  It is called by UIKit after your view controller has been loaded. If you have code in viewDidLoad that you want to run again, you should move that code to its own function and call that function from `viewDidLoad`